# Subtract array from another in .net

Tags: .net, arrays, compare, subtraction

Is there any easy way to remove the contents of one array from another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have LINQ

```
array.Except(array2);
```

Comment: this would also remove the duplicates? how to remove the contents of one array from another? e.g. when {2,3,5} is removed from {2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7}, it should return {2, 2, 7}.